# How to renable ctrl+e "DO file" in Visual Foxpro editor?

Tags: visual-foxpro

For the past several years through last night (2017-03-02), `ctrl+e` in a code file has executed that file `DO <currentfile>.prg` Today it does nothing. both `ctrl` and `e` work for other purposes, and I've rebooted the computer. I've not yet found an obvious way to access application keybindings.

VFP 9.0 SP2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only files opened with `MODIFY COMMAND <filename>` are eligible for execution. Other file types are opened with `MODIFY FILE` and are not eligible.

*(Starting up I had edited a `MODIFY FILE` to open my program, not realizing that there were two different `MODIFY` commands)*

Comment: So have you solved your problem or are you still having issues?